# Limitar numeros enteros y decimales

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, numberformat

estoy trabajando un pequeño input que solo admita cierto número de enteros y decimales, he encontrado partes de código y solo he logrado limitar las decimales:

```
<input type="text" name="moneda nac" id="moneda_nac" value="10" onkeypress="return filterFloat(event,this);"/>

function filterFloat(evt,input){
// Backspace = 8, Enter = 13, ‘0′ = 48, ‘9′ = 57, ‘.’ = 46, ‘-’ = 43
var key = window.Event ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;   
var chark = String.fromCharCode(key);
var tempValue = input.value+chark;
var isNumber = (key >= 48 && key <= 57);
var isSpecial = (key == 8 || key == 13 || key == 0 ||  key == 46);
if(isNumber || isSpecial){
    return filter(tempValue);
}        

return false;    
    
}
function filter(__val__){
    var preg = /^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]{0,2})$/; 
    return (preg.test(__val__) === true);
}
```

Como ven esto solo restringe las decimales, pero quiero restringir igual los enteros para que solo quede un entero y dos decimales ejemplo:

> 1.40

¿Que tengo que modificar en el código para restringir que solo admita un entero y dos decimales?

Comment: Partiendo de la base que estamos validando strigns, un entero (positivo) y dos decimales sería `/^\d\.\d{2}$/gm`.